# My program stopped working suddenly, I did not change anything that I remember, and it now gives the second error: javafx.fxml.LoadException

Tags: java, fxml

(Sorry my english, I'm using the Google Translate) My program stopped working suddenly, I did not change anything that I remember, and it now gives the second error: 
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
file:/C:/Users/soare/Documents/NetBeansProjects/ProjetoAcademia/dist/run502448431/ProjetoAcademia.jar!/projetoacademia/FXMLDocument.fxml

My main class:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ProjetoAcademia extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    try {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("Sistema de Gerenciamento de Controle de Academia do IFPI (SGCA-IFPI)");
        stage.show();
    } catch (Exception error) {
        System.out.println("aqui>>>>" + error + "<<<<<");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);

}

}
```

Here's the rest of my program (It's grid for the platform)
[4Shared](https://www.4shared.com/zip/Ut50Q1-0ei/ProjetoAcademia.html) or [Mega](https://mega.nz/#!IkMV1QAC!Kt5spc1Jeqyk6trbvfaWM4UyHyo0U-3PI-BLxq0wcF8)

This is my sql code:

```
create table matricula (
cpf integer NOT NULL,
rg integer NOT NULL,
cod_matricula character varying primary key NOT NULL,
)
create table aluno(
nome character varying NOT NULL,
telefone integer NOT NULL,
idade integer NOT NULL,
email character varying NOT NULL,
id_aluno serial NOT NULL,
cod_matricula_alunofk character varying NOT NULL
)
create table professor
(    nome character varying NOT NULL,
idade integer NOT NULL,
id_professor serial NOT NULL,
cod_matricula_professorfk character varying NOT NULL,
telefone integer NOT NULL,
email character varying NOT NULL
)
create table servidor(
nome character varying NOT NULL,
idade integer NOT NULL,
id_servidor serial,
cod_matricula_servidorfk character varying NOT NULL,
telefone integer NOT NULL,
email character varying NOT NULL
)
create table indicacao_medica
(tipos_aparelho character varying NOT NULL,
observacao character varying,
id_indicacao serial NOT NULL
)
create table inscricao
(turno character varying NOT NULL,
id_inscricao serial NOT NULL,
id_alunofk integer,
id_indicacaofk integer,
id_professorfk integer,
id_servidorfk integer
)
```

Comment: What does your project directory structure look like? Did you move your .fxml file?

Comment: It looks like your program is having trouble opening an external file.  Does the file named in the exception message still exist?  Can you open it via another program, such as a text editor?

Comment: Thanks all, I was able to make the error stop when deleting the line "clTurnoT.setCellValueFactory (new PropertyValueFactory <> ("turno"));" of the "private void initialize". I noticed that it is in the Controller code, but not in FXML, so the error

Comment: Thanks all, I was able to make the error stop when deleting the line "clTurnoT.setCellValueFactory (new PropertyValueFactory <> ("turno"));" of the "private void initialize". I noticed that it is in the Controller code, but not in FXML, so the error

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be here:

> I did not change anything that I remember

And the solution to that problem is called versioning control system (VCS). It helps you saving states during programming. You can revert from a non-working state to a previous state which was known working. And you can compare the differences.

There are many tools out there, implementing VCS: Git, SVN (Subversion), TFS (Team Foundation Server).

Other than that, you should probably check whether `FXMLDocument.fxml` becomes part of your JAR file. and make sure that the path matches:

```
FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("projetoacademia/FXMLDocument.fxml"));
```